# Different transition-duration for each transition-property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to use different duration for each transition property. For example for width I want to  have a transition with 0.3s and for height 0.6s.

Is it possible in CSS3 ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sure, you can list different transitions with a comma separated list: `transition: color 0.25s ease, border 1s linear`

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to separate `transform: translateX(..)` from `transform: rotate(..)` in transition ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as `transform` is considered one bundled property. What might work is to wrap whatever you're transforming in a few wrappers, one for each property that you need to transition differently. Or alternatively, use javascript to trigger classes with their own respective transitions and transformations.

Answer (score 5):

`transition: width 0.3s, height 0.6s;`

Just use the shorthand `transition` property instead. Don't forget vendor prefixes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dwgg/